# storing blob data in relation to the user who uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-blob-storage

I am working with **BLOB** storage in asp.net MVC 5 application and i want to store my BLOB files in relation to the user who uploaded them.

First of all as we see this, when we load an asp.net MVC application with **individual user accounts**, visual studio loads a default database and model, controller and view files for this individual user accounts option. Using this, if we run the application the user can create an account and can login and logout.

In my application, i want that if the user creates an account, he/she can upload and download files(BLOB files) from their account. Is their a way that i can use the default settings using **individual user accounts** and store my BLOB data in the same table? or create a new table for BLOB files and integrate them?

Comment: what you by `... and store my BLOB data in ...` what is this your Blob data ?! What exactly do you ask?

Comment: my Blob data is images, videos, PDFs and related files @astaykov